# Java Scanner.nextLine() not waiting for input

Tags: java

I have several methods that I've used previously to accept user input and return it as a certain data type to the method that calls for it.  I have used these methods, or variations of them, in previous projects.

I've adopted the method that I used for string to select the first char given and return that, so that I can use this in a menu.  Every time I start the application, the main menu appears and waits for user input.  After receiving this input, the program loops continuously until stopped.  Here is my method for capturing the char:

```
private char getUserChar(String prompt) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String tempString = "";
        tempString = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        char userChar = tempString.charAt(0);
        return userChar;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code loops due to the try/catch block, as scan.nextLine() never waits for the next input.  Without it, the exception is typically related to not finding a new line.  I've tried the while(scan.hasNextLine()) that seems to work for other people; however, once the time for input arrives, it never breaks out of the loop.  I also don't believe I'm tripping up on the nextInt() issue that everyone seems to have troubles with. I'll post the code for the entire class below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import controller.Controller;
public class TUI {
    private Controller controller;
    public TUI() {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean wantToQuit = false;
        char userInput = 0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Mart.");
        do{
            userInput = mainMenu();
            if(isUserInputValid(userInput))
                switch(userInput){
                    case 'a': addItem();
                    break;
                    case 'r': controller.removeItem();
                    break;
                    case 'i': controller.printInventory();
                    break;
                    case 'p': controller.customerPurchase();
                    break;
                    case 'w': controller.weeklyStock();
                    break;
                    case 'c': wantToQuit = true;
                    break;
                }
            else System.out.println("\nMainMenu");



        } while(!(wantToQuit));
        System.out.println("WolfMart is now closed.  Thank you and good-bye.");
    }




    private boolean isUserInputValid(char userInput) {
        char[] testSet = {'a', 'r', 'i', 'p', 'c', 'w'};
        for(char currentChar : testSet) {
            if(currentChar == userInput)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private char mainMenu() {
        System.out.println();
        controller.printInventory();
        String mainMenuSelection = "What would you like to do: (a)dd item, (r)emove item, print (i)nventory, " +
            "(p)urchase by customer, (c)lose store?\r\n";

        char mainMenuInput = getUserChar(mainMenuSelection);
        return mainMenuInput;
    }

    private char getUserChar(String prompt) {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String tempString = "";
            tempString = scan.nextLine();
            scan.close();
            char userChar = tempString.charAt(0);
            return userChar;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return 0;
    }


    private int getUserInt(String prompt) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInt = -1;
        try {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            userInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("I did not recognize your command, please try again.");
        }
        scan.close();
        return userInt;
    }

    private String getUserString(String prompt) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userString = null;
        try{
            System.out.print(prompt);
            userString = scan.nextLine();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("I did not recognize your command, please try again.");
        }
        scan.close();
        return userString;
    }

    private double getUserDouble(String prompt) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double userDouble = -1.0;
        try {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            userDouble = Double.parseDouble(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("I did not recognize your command, please try again.");
        }
        scan.close();
        return userDouble;
    }

    private void addItem() {
        String itemName = "";
        double price;
        int quantity;
        String namePrompt = "Enter the name of the item being added to the inventory: ";
        String pricePrompt = "Enter the cost of " + itemName + ": ";
        String quantityPrompt = "Enter the quantity of " + itemName + ": ";
        itemName = getUserString(namePrompt);
        price = getUserDouble(pricePrompt);
        quantity = getUserInt(quantityPrompt);
        controller.addItem(itemName, quantity, price);
    }




}
```

Comment: You're closing `System.in` each time you close the `Scanner`s. You should only really need a single `Scanner` anyways.

Comment: Haha... I could kick myself in the face.  My last programs didn't close them and so they worked, but this new version of Eclipse was telling me to close them each time.  I guess I will try and rework that, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124793/java-scanner-nextline-not-waiting-for-input/12124906#comment16213611_12124793), the problem is that **you're closing `System.in` each time you do something like this**:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
...
scan.close();
```

Now, look at the specification of [`Scanner.nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

> **Throws**:
>
> - `NoSuchElementException` - if no line was found
> - `IllegalStateException` - if this scanner is closed

Now, since the scanner *itself* is not closed, an `IllegalStateException` will not be thrown. Instead, as you mentioned before, the other exception, "*typically related to not finding a new line*", -- `NoSuchElementException` -- is thrown.

Presuming this you're using JDK 7, you can see how this works by examining [`Scanner.throwFor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.throwFor%28%29):

```
if ((sourceClosed) && (position == buf.limit()))
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
```

Since your exception is thrown, a value of `0` is returned by `getUserChar`, which is then used in the `run` loop:

```
    do {
        userInput = mainMenu();
        if (isUserInputValid(userInput)) {
            ...
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nMainMenu");
        }
    } while (!wantToQuit);
```

Since the input is invalid, you're caught in a loop printing `"\nMainMenu\n"`.

To correct the issue, try to use a single `Scanner` and don't close `System.in` ;-)

Comment: Wow, and I was expecting maybe one or two lines. Nice answer! 1+

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Haha I couldn't figure out why it kept skipping through everything when I debugged it, but this makes a ton of sense now.

Comment: OMG i have been researching this for a while, and yes i was using more than one scanners and closing one of them and i could not wrap my head around it. thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please **don't close** the `Scanner`.

```
scan.close();    // Don't do it.
```

Doing that is causing the problem.