# Java reading out data from Console with Scanner goes wrong in extended Class

Tags: java

I have the following Classes:

```
public class Human {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Human(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter Firstname");
        setFirstName(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter Lastname");
        setLastName(in.nextLine());
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Customer extends Human{
    private long customerNumber;
    private String customerCompanyName;
    static long customerNumberCounter = 0;

    public Customer(){
        super();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        setCustomerNumber(customerNumberCounter);
        customerNumberCounter ++;
        System.out.println("Please enter Companyname");
        setCustomerCompanyName(in.nextLine());
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When i call the following Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
    System.out.println(aCustomer.giveFullName());
}
```

The Programm throwes the following Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)   at
>   customers.Customer.(Customer.java:17)   at
>   customers.Customer.main(Customer.java:22)

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, since I can create an Object of Class Human without any problems but when I create a Customer, the Error pops up directly after entering the LastName in the Human Constructor.

I already renamed the Scanner and so on but that didn't solve the problem.

Anybody got a Solution for this?

Comment: Which one of the two scanner is reading your typing when you get to read the company name? I wouldn't like to use two different scanner. Just create one and get a ref to it for both classes.

Comment: Use buffer reader in place of scanner it is more reliable. Use its readLine() method and also InputStreamReader with system.in, system.in is used to read data from console.

Comment: @ Jkike each Constructor has his own Scanner

Comment: take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124793/java-scanner-nextline-not-waiting-for-input

Comment: I don't know if mark this question as duplicated, but your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13042296/3998458), the main problem is because when you close your scanner the first time, it close `System.in` too and apparently it can't be reopen... You should instanciate this object and close it only at the end.

Comment: @ Alexandro im creating a new Scanner object in each constructor! But i will give it a try

Comment: super wierd, but it works this way! but the compiler now wants me to close the scanner in the human constructor... well if i do so it doesnt work anymore :D

Comment: @TeaTime closing the first scanner also closes `System.in` (the underlying stream). compiler warnings are OK in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before read the next,you close the scanner.So it can not read the line:

```
public Human(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter Firstname");
    setFirstName(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter Lastname");
    setLastName(in.nextLine());
    //in.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes they do, i just didnt want to copy itbecause the code itself would become really large